# Net::HTTP POST with XML Payload and some URL Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, post

Just a quick question,

when I do

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(path)
```

Can I do

```
path = '/api/v1/baskets?apiKey=' + api_key + '&sig=' + sig + '&time=' + time
```

Where api_key sig and time are some string

or do I need to do

```
path = '/api/v1/baskets'
request.set_form_data({'apiKey' => api_key, 'sig' => sig, 'time' => time})
```

is there any difference or are they pretty much the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are pretty much the same, `set_form_data` does a urlencode.

Here is what it does in `set_form_data`  [link](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTPHeader.html#M000638)

```
def set_form_data(params, sep = '&')
  self.body = params.map {|k,v| "#{urlencode(k.to_s)}=#{urlencode(v.to_s)}" }.join(sep)
  self.content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
end
```

When in doubt always refer [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org).